Octree not detecting collisons with objects that are at a 90deg angle to the floor
A collision with any object that is not 90deg from the floor it detects but when I have for example a border or a cube in the scene it just goes straight through the mesh. The floor works fine.
 playerCollisions() {
        const result = this.octree.capsuleIntersect(this.player.collider);
        this.player.onFloor = false;
    
        if (result) {
         
            this.player.onFloor = result.normal.y > 0;
    
            if (!this.player.onFloor) {
          
                const velocityProjection = result.normal.dot(this.player.velocity);
                this.player.velocity.addScaledVector(result.normal, -velocityProjection);
            }
    
            // Translate the player's collider out of the collision
            this.player.collider.translate(result.normal.multiplyScalar(result.depth));

also sometimes it goes through once and if I move the player back and forth the second time it registers the collision.

An octree is a general concept. What specific octree library are you using?
